# How can I Iterate over enum Flag alias?

Tags: python, python-3.11

**Question**

How can I iterate over enum Flag alias?

```py
from enum import Flag

class Color(Flag):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
    GREEN = 4
    WHITE = RED | BLUE | GREEN # <- How do I retrieve this alias?

list(Color) 
# [<Color.RED: 1>, <Color.BLUE: 2>, <Color.GREEN: 4>]
# How do I include Color.White and other aliases in this list?
```

From documentation, `__iter__` returns only non-alias members.

> `__iter__(self)`:
> Returns all contained non-alias members
> Changed in version 3.11: Aliases are no longer returned during iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`__members__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names) to get a mapping of enum name to value.

From python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names):

> `__members__` is a read-only ordered mapping of member_name:member items. It is only available on the class.

```
mapping = Color.__members__
# mappingproxy({'RED': <Color.RED: 1>,
#              'BLUE': <Color.BLUE: 2>,
#              'GREEN': <Color.GREEN: 4>,
#              'WHITE': <Color.WHITE: 7>})

colors_list = list(mapping.values())
# [<Color.RED: 1>, <Color.BLUE: 2>, <Color.GREEN: 4>, <Color.WHITE: 7>]
```

There's a caveat to this though. If you have enum values that are similar then you'd get the same value returned for them.

```
class Color(Flag):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 1
print(Color.__members__)
# mappingproxy({'RED': <Color.RED: 1>, 'BLUE': <Color.RED: 1>})
```

---

<sub>Useful links: [Enum HOWTO: Iteration](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html?highlight=__members__#iteration), [Enum HOWTO: Duplicating enum members and values](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html?highlight=__members__#duplicating-enum-members-and-values)</sub>

Comment: The list comprehension can be further simplified as `list(mapping.values)`

Comment: @pho Yeah true that's simpler than list comp. Thanks.